# how to bind input text in sales force using lightning component give the example

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component controller="LeadRep" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global"  >
  <aura:attribute name="v.contacts" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="details" type="String[]"/>

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

   <!-- Use a data table from the Lightning Design System: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/ -->

 <article class="slds-card">
  <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">

    <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
      <div class="slds-media__figure">
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="Rep_Lead">
          <lightning:icon iconName="doctype:image" alternativeText="Doc image" />
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Rep Lead</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-media__body">
        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Rep_Lead">
            <span>Rep Lead</span>
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </header>

  </div>
  <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">Card Body</div>
  </article>

 <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">        

 <h2>Contact Information</h2>

     <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
  <div class="slds-col">

 <span><ui:inputText label="Dodge Report Number"  value="{!v.contacts.dodge__DR_NBR__c}" /></span>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

       var action = component.get("c.getProjectDetails");
      //action.setparm
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
             if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    component.set("{!v.contacts}",response.getReturnValue());
                }

            var dodge__DR_NBR__c = response.getState();
            if (dodge__DR_NBR__c === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.contacts", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            }

            }
        );


        var action1 = component.get("c.getProjectList");
        action1.setCallback(this,function(response){
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    component.set("{!v.details}",response.getReturnValue());
                }

            var dodge__DR_NBR__c = response.getState();
            if (dodge__DR_NBR__c === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.details", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            }

            }
        );

         $A.enqueueAction(action);
         $A.enqueueAction(action1);
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Providing the code you have is an important part of a question, but it's usually not the _only_ part of a question. Please point out where, exactly, your problem is. Something like "I tried to use `{!v.contacts.myField}` near the bottom of the page, but I'm getting this error: <complete error message>`. You should include these details in your question by making an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

You make like to read [Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_overview.htm) and [Value provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm) in Lightning Experience.

Expressions allow you to make calculations and access property values and other data within component markup. Use expressions for dynamic output or passing values into components by assigning them to attributes.

Value providers are a way to access data. Value providers encapsulate related values together, similar to how an object encapsulates properties and methods.

Coming to an working Example:-

```
<aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String"/>
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="header">Live Input Text</h2>
        <lightning:input name="input8" value="{! v.firstName }" placeholder="type your first name..." label="Text field with attribute binding" />
        <p>
            FirstName: {! v.firstName }
        </p>
    </div>
```

I am using an attribute named firstName of type String. The lightning:input field of type text binds its value in that attribute.

[image]

Coming to your Component:-

As I can see you are trying to bind the contact field values with text field. I suggest:-

1. Create one attribute of type Contact.

> < aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" />

and when binding it with field, use as below :-

```
< ui:inputText label="Dodge Report Number"  value="{!v.contact.dodge__DR_NBR__c}" />
```

Instead of using ui namespace base component, Use **Lightning namespace** base component.